# I want to replace NaN values with "0" but not able to with the below code

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I am trying to replace the NaN values with "0" with the below code, its not giving any error but there's no change in the dataframe also, can you tell me where is my mistake?

```
df2 = df_num.iloc[:,[8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]]
df2.replace(to_replace ="NaN",value =0, inplace=True)
df2

[the image to my dataframe output is here][1]


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LamrH.png
```

Comment: Try `df2 = df2.fillna('o')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you passed `to_replace="NaN"`.

Note that you actually passed here a **string** containing just these 3 letters.

In *Pandas* you can pass `np.nan`, but only as the value to be **assigned**
to a cell in a DataFrame. The same pertains to a *Numpy* array.

You can not pass `to_replace=np.nan`, because the comparison rules are
that one *np.nan* is **NOT** equal to another *np.nan*.

One of possible solutions is to run:

```
df2 = df2.where(~df2.isna(), 0)
```

Other, simpler solution, as *richardec* suggested, is to use *fillna*,
but the argument should be *0* (zero) not "o" (a char):

```
df2 = df2.fillna(0)
```